# Are there any PC-98 emulators for Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation, games, emulation

That is, are there any programs for emulating an [NEC PC-9801](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NEC_PC-9801) (the computer the first five [Touhou](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touhou_Project) games were made for) designed to run natively on Ubuntu (or Linux in general)? I haven't been able to find any.

Answer (score 2):

I may have found a solution. From the [Touhou Wiki](http://en.touhouwiki.net/wiki/Running_in_Linux_and_MacOS_X#PC-98_Games):

> Neko Project II, T98Next and Anex86 work just fine under Wine. Also, if you're into two-player PoDD with a gamepad, JoyToKey also works under Wine.
>
> There is also a port of Neko Project II for Linux and Mac OS X called Xnp2. However, as of this writing there are some sound problems that need to be investigated; using np2fmgen in Wine is recommended instead.

I haven't had time to test any of them yet, but it sounds promising...

Answer (score 0):

`dosbox` emulates an 8086+ DOS PC.

Comment: Could you perhaps add some more detail to this please?

Comment: @Seth, like what?

Comment: Instructions for installing it,  a little information on how to use it?,  etc.

Comment: PC-98 is 8086 but not IBM PC DOS compatible, so won't work with dosbox